# JSF update view don't change the bean

Tags: hibernate, jsf-2.2

I got a basic edit form for a "document" entity (I use JSF2 and Hibernate),  the "create" form works fine, but the "edit" doesn't. So the edit form show the current document values, but when it send new values, the backbean doesn't get them and works like with old entity.

parts of my edit.xhtml :

```
<ui:param name="doc" value="#{document.getDocument()}" />

<h:form id="editForm">
    <h:inputHidden name="ID" id="ID" value="#{doc.ID}" />

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-label">Title *</span>
        <h:inputText type="text" class="input-group-field" size="30" name="title" id="title" a:required="required" a:placeholder="title" value="#{doc.title}"/>
    </div>
    <h:message for="title"></h:message>

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-label">Subtitle</span>
        <h:inputText type="text" class="input-group-field" size="30" name="subtitle" id="subtitle" a:placeholder="subtitle" value="#{doc.subtitle}" />
    </div>
    <h:message for="subtitle"></h:message>

    <div class="button-group">
        <h:button outcome="/main?faces-redirect=true" type="button" value="Cancel"></h:button>
       <h:commandButton action="${doc.save}" value="Save">
           <f:ajax render="@form" execute=":editForm" event="keyup"/> 
       </h:commandButton>
    </div>

</h:form>
```

parts of my document bean :

```
@ManagedBean
@Entity
@ViewScoped
public class document implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int ID;
    @NotNull
    private String title;
    private String subtitle;

    //Getters Setters....

    @Transient
    public document getDocument() {
        documentDAO = new DocumentDAO();
        Optional<document> doc =  documentDAO.read(this.ID);
        if(doc.isPresent()) {           
            return doc.get();
        }else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String save() {
         documentDAO = new DocumentDAO();
         System.out.println("Saving Document (" + this.getTitle() + ")...");
         documentDAO.update(this);
         if(this.error == null || this.error.isEmpty())
              return "/list?faces-redirect=true";
         else 
             return "edit";             
     }
```

If I edit the document title, was for example "test", by "testok", and send the form, the system print "Saving Document (test)...", and not "Saving Document (testok)...", despite of I can see that "testok" has been send in the post html request (using web dev panel of the navigator).
I don't have form inside a form.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, by using a copy of the bean for the edit, and load it in the view params, retrieving the id from previous list page.
In the header of my edit.xhtml:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{document.ID}"/>
    <f:viewAction action="#{document.getDocument()}" />
</f:metadata>
```

In my document bean:

```
@Transient
public void getDocument() {
    documentDAO = new DocumentDAO();
    Optional<document> doc =  documentDAO.read(this.ID);
    if(doc.isPresent()) {           
        document d = doc.get();         
        this.title = d.title;
        this.subtitle = d.subtitle;
    }
}
```

And now it works fine, it update the bean. Just copying all the members variables is a bit crappy, maybe there's a nicer way.